# Pass same dynamic data (user type) to all render request in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am creating my first web app using django and I have a custom model which has the user type of each user stored and I want the menu options off my html to be customized based on the user type. I am implementing that by using the if django template tag butfor that I require the user type of the user requesting the page to be passed whenever I call the render function. So is there any method through which this data is sent automatically to all the requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `request` object within your template which has a reference to the current user through `request.user`. Use it in your template:

```
{% if request.user.type == <UserType1> %}
    # some logic
{% elif request.user.type == <UserType1> %}
    # etc.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks!
It was not what I was looking for (and I think there is no way we can do that) but your method helped me implement that feature.